# ORACLE MULTIPLE TABLE INDEXES ON GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, index, optimization, view

I have a VIEW with multiple tables, it has a group by statement containing multiple columns from each table. The problem is access to the view takes 4,5 seconds and ideally should take less than 1.

When I run the Query Plan, it seems SORT(GROUP BY) is the most expensive statement. I tried to create indexes on the columns present in the group by statement but oracle doesnt want to use them.

What could be another solution?

Comment: The CBO changes every patch.  Please post 4-digit version of your database.  Personally,  I'd like to see the query and the plan.  Oh, make sure the stats are uoto date.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)